# AutoHotKey в Java

Tags: java

n-ое время пользовался программой AutoHotKey для того,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "w" у меня выполнялась определенная последовательность клавиш в игре (иначе говоря "макрос"),вопрос следующий :

Как реализовать подобное в Java?
Смотрел я класс java.awt.Robot, делал простенькое приложение, но проблема в том,что,чтобы считывать нажатия клавиш необходимо делать окно приложения с кодом активным, а просто так изменить это не удается.

Кто-нибудь решал эту проблему? Если да,то как.
Если нет, то куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение следующее :**

*Подключаем WindowsAPI и просто манипулируем скриптами написанными на AutoHotKey*